# Installing RQuantLib on Linux

Tags: r, quantlib

We have been trying to install RQuantLib on a redhat linux machine.  After a month (embarassingly long time!) of trial and error, we have succesfully compiled the latest version of boost and also quantlib.  I am not a linux expert at all, so I am having a little trouble debugging the compile flags when I run install.packages("RQuantLib").  Rcpp is installed and working perfectly as well.

The error message below details the issue.  I am confused because the file I think it should want (libQuantLib.so.0) exists in /usr/local/lib.  Sorry that this is most likely a stupid question, but I think we are very close to having access to quantlib in R on linux.

The error message is below:

```
g++ -I/apps/R/R-3.0.0/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/apps/R/R-3.0.0/library/Rcpp/include"  -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/loca
l/include/boost  -I. -fpic  -g -O2  -c zero.cpp -o zero.o

g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RQuantLib.so asian.o barrier_binary.o bermudan.o bonds.o calendars.o curves.o daycounter.o discount.o hullwhi
te.o implieds.o utils.o vanilla.o zero.o -L/apps/R/R-3.0.0/library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/apps/R/R-3.0.0/library/Rcpp/lib -L/usr/local/lib
-L/usr/local/lib -lQuantLib

installing to /apps/R/R-3.0.0/library/RQuantLib/libs
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/apps/R/R-3.0.0/library/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so':
  libQuantLib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the post to make the error message more clear, I was just trying to figure out how to do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might just be that the dynamic loader hasn't realized yet that you've added QuantLib.
Try adding the line

```
/usr/local/lib
```

to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (if it's not already there) and then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

On your system there should be man pages for both `ld.so` and `ldconfig` if you want to understand what you're doing, which is always a good proposition. Never execute commands given by strangers on the internet, especially in `sudo` mode :)

After you do the above, you should be able to load `libQuantLib`.

Comment: We ended up setting up a symbolic link- but this solution may be more elegant- thanks for the help!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue when trying to run a Docker Image on Linux -- does this imply a missing library that I need to install? @rlh2

Comment: this is actually far easier in docker in my experience. Assuming you have debian in your docker, if you apt-get libboost-all-dev and follow the steps here: https://www.quantlib.org/install/linux.shtml, things just kind of work. As the link says, you don't even have to install from source, you can pull down a package as well (see "installation from package repositories"