# Installing RQuantLib on RStudio AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, quantitative-finance, rstudio-server, quantlib

there have been some similar questions ([Installing RQuantLib on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644436/installing-rquantlib-on-linux)), but none related to the AWS RStudio environment. After trying the usual rute

```
install.packages('RQuantLib');
library(devtools)
install_github("eddelbuettel/rquantlib")
```

I get the following error (in both cases):

```
configure: error: Please install QuantLib before trying to build RQuantLib.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RQuantLib’.
```

Also, all of a sudden (after upgrading R on my local machine from 3.4.4 to 3.5.0) RQuantLib stopped working also on my local Windows machine:

```
 Error in system(full, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = quiet, ...) : 
 running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-  environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 1
```

After following the directions on the Github page I tried the following:

```
if (!require("drat")) install.packages("drat")
drat::addRepo("ghrr")
install.packages("RQuantLib", type="binary")
```

but got the follwoing error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://ghrr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
cannot open URL 'https://ghrr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘RQuantLib’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.5.0)
```

What else could I try? The AWS problem has a higher priority, although I would really like to be able to use RQuantLib on my local machine again, so any help would be really appreciated.

A small end note: The RQuantLib library compiles succesfully on the Debian 16.04 AWS AMI, but not on the RStudio AMI.

Answer (score 0):

Windows builds, just like Unix builds, require QuantLib to be present which has its challenges.

The most recent upload restores this ability, utilising a GitHub repo with a prebuilt version of QuantLib.  Try installing RQuantLib 0.4.5 now on Windows; you should get a binary from CRAN as can been [on the CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib).